# What is this line doing in my rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Ok so i have my users_controller update action with has this code and this is in production and working and i want to know what this line is doing

```
@user.attributes = { 'role_ids' => [] }.merge(params[:user])
```

and I dont understand how this is setting the role_ids and if there is a better way to do this

@user is the User and .attributes doesnt have role_ids in it so how does this work ....here is my relationships

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, :through => :role_users
  has_many :role_users

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles, :through => :role_users
  has_many :role_users

class RoleUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :role
  belongs_to :user
end
```

and the params are

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"GV/BbOZdKn7SkzD8zydceVdwA+fga=", "user"=>{"id"=>"629", "company_id"=>"1", "active"=>"1", "role_ids"=>["1", "3", "1"], "notification_ids"=>["1", "2", "3"]}, "company"=>"11", "id"=>"621"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below line checks the role_ids, if role_ids in params[:user] then take that one else take empty array :

```
@user.attributes = { 'role_ids' => [] }.merge(params[:user])
```

means merge works like :

```
params[:user][:role_ids] = (params[:user].include? 'role_ids') ?  params[:user][:role_ids] : []
```

so you are getting role_ids like

```
irb(main):026:0> { 'role_ids' => [] }.merge(params[:user])
=> {"role_ids"=>["1", "3", "1"], "id"=>"629", "company_id"=>"1", "active"=>"1", "notification_ids"=>["1", "2", "3"]}
```

Comment: so does the params[:user] get altered

Comment: Edited my answer , Please take a look .

Comment: No params[:user] will not altered, it will return new hash . Try same thing on console .

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that the ui for this is a series of checkboxes, with name `role_ids[]` and where the value is the id of the rule. If the boxes for roles 2,3,4 were ticked this would result in the `role_ids` parameter being set to `[2,3,4]`

The only niggle is when you want to give someone no roles. If all the checkboxes are unpicked then no `role_ids` parameter is submitted at all.

```
@user.attributes = { 'role_ids' => [] }.merge(params[:user])
```

ensures when none of the checkboxes are ticked the user actually has all of their existing roles removed

Comment: does the params[:user] get altered after this merge

Comment: no - merge returns a new hash formed by adding the keys/valyes from its argument (params[:user]) to the hash it is called on {'role_ids => []}

Answer (score 2):

See [Hash#merge](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-merge) for details about how this function work. Here it just makes sure that if `params[:user][:role_ids]` doesn't exist then it will save an empty array instead.

You can do it this way too :

```
params[:user][:role_ids] ||= []
```

I think it's much nicer and readable.

Comment: I think you meant that to be `||=`.

Answer (score 0):

If there are duplicates in the hashes then [Hash#merge](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-merge) return the value of the entries in the hash given as the parameter to #merge. There's a `"role_ids"=>["1", "3", "1"]` in your params and thus the `role_ids` will be set to that.